# OpenTK in Xamarin.Mac: How to obtain modern OpenGL graphics context? (e.g. OpenGL 3.3 / GLSL 330)

Tags: macos, opengl, xamarin, opentk

I am developing a cross-platform graphics application, which uses OpenTK. On Windows, I can reference OpenTK and OpenTK.GLControl dlls to initialize my rendering context like this, and in particular, request a specific [modern] OpenGL graphics context (in this case, OpenGL 3.3):

```
int major = 3;
int minor = 3;
var control = new OpenTK.GLControl(GraphicsMode.Default, major, minor, GraphicsContextFlags.Default);
```

There are some examples on the Xamarin website ([Introduction to OpenTK](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/mac/platform-features/opentk/) and [MonoMacGameView](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/mac/MonoMacGameWindow/)) and they demonstrate using OpenTK for Mac like this:

```
Game = new MonoMacGameView (ContentView.Frame);
ContentView = Game;
Game.Run();
```

However, when I do this, and then check the OpenGL version like this:

```
string version = GL.GetString(StringName.Version); // "2.1 INTEL-10.14.66"
string glsl = GL.GetString(StringName.ShadingLanguageVersion); // "1.20"
```

...I get what appears to be an obsolete context, and furthermore, I can't seem to specify that I want anything else. My system (OS X 10.11.5, Mac mini (Late 2014) Intel Iris) should be able to support OpenGL 4.1, according to this: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202823

Of greater concern, the Xamarin OpenTK examples use Immediate Mode (e.g. GL.Begin), which has long since been removed from the OpenGL core profile specification. So, my questions are:

1. Is it possible to obtain a modern OpenGL context in OpenTK on Mac? If so, how?
2. Is there an equivalent of OpenTK.GLControl for Mac other than MonoMacGameView, or is that the preferred (and only) option?
3. When setting up my solution in Xamarin, I have a Portable Class Library (with all my platform-independent code), and then separate projects (one for Mac and one for Windows) that reference it. The Windows project references OpenTK dlls; and the Mac project references OpenTK via NuGet (as described in the Intro tutorial linked above). Is this a sensible way to structure a cross-platform (Windows/Mac) solution that depends on OpenTK? Is there any way to use the same OpenTK dll references for both Mac and Windows?
4. If it's the case that OpenTK cannot be used with an OpenGL 3.3+ context on Mac, is there an alternative approach to accessing OpenGL in Xamarin on Mac?

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You need to ask for a forward compatible profile, replace `GraphicsContextFlags.Default` with `GraphicsContextFlags.ForwardCompatible`.

I'm using OpenGL 3.3 with OpenTK on Mac by inheriting from `GameWindow` class and initializing the context in the constructor like this:

```
using OpenTK;
using OpenTK.Graphics;

class Program : GameWindow
{
    public Program() : 
        base( width, height, GraphicsMode.Default, "App Name", 0, DisplayDevice.Default, 3, 3, GraphicsContextFlags.ForwardCompatible )
    {
       ...
```

I use Xamarin Studio and downloaded OpenTK from its website, didn't use NuGet.

Comment: As I explained above, the first code snippet is an example of something that is available with OpenTK on Windows. That is not my problem though. My problem is being able to specify the requested version *on Mac OSX* using OpenTK and Xamarin Studio... :-/.

Comment: @MaxxAMillion I expanded my answer to explain how I use 3.3 on Mac

Comment: This is encouraging! How are you using OpenTK on Mac though? How did you obtain the build (e.g. built-from-source or NuGet or downloaded .dlls?) What are you using for an IDE (e.g. VS, Xamarin Studio) ? What project type is the above code in? Is what you have done compatible with Xamarin? Could be hypothetically be put into a Portable Class Library?

Comment: @MaxxAMillion I use Xamarin Studio and downloaded OpenTK from OpenTK's website. I don't remember the other details and don't have my system set up for it now but here's my game with project files and source: https://github.com/bioglaze/flappy

Comment: I downloaded your Flappy code, and confirmed that I can obtain a modern context on Mac running in Xamarin. Creating a new empty Windows Console App project and referencing your OpenTK.dll also works. However, I cannot load it from within a Xamarin.Mac App (Xamarin project type Mac > Cocoa App. I get a TypeLoad exception. Thankfully, I was able to replicate all the above using my own build of OpenTK.dll. The problems that remain are:
-- Can't use these .dlls from within Xamarin.Mac app.
-- Analogous commands do *not* work for the GLControl.

Comment: Any ideas why this would work with the GameWindow (in OpenTK.dll) but not with the GLControl (in OpenTK.GLControl.dll)? Alternatively, is there a way to embed a "GameWindow" like it were a control (or "view" perhaps) inside a Mac app?